# Reference to Animator component not appearing in the inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, inspector

### I have already tried to look into this... but no luck..

Sprite renderer, and mover references, work fine they appear in the inspector as I want them to.

However I am having issues in **FILE 2** I am unsure of how to Serialize the Animator in the inspector.

**FILE 1**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "EnemyConfig", menuName =  "Enemies/Enemy config", order = 0)]
public class EnemyConfig : ScriptableObject
{
    public float moverSpeed;
    //public float zRotation;
    public Sprite sprite;
    
    public Animator animator;
}
```

**FILE 2**

```
//EnemyController.CS
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public EnemyConfig config;
    [SerializeField]
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;


    //Want to get a reference to the animator component appear in the inspector
    //This is my issue...--------------------------------------]

    [SerializeField]
    private GetComponent<Animator> animatorController;

    //----------------------------


    private Mover mover;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        mover = GetComponent<Mover>();
        if(mover != null)
        {
            mover.speed = config.moverSpeed;
        } 
        
        
        if(config.sprite != null)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = config.sprite; 
        }
        

        // related to the animator
        if(config.animator != null)
        {
            animatorController.animator = config.animator;
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see how the Sprite reference, and mover reference appear in the inspector.
I am trying to do the same with the **Animator**

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just public Animator anim;?

Comment: Remove that `GetComponent` from your field declaration ... doubt that it even compiles without errors ;) It should only be `[SerializeField] private Animator animatorController;` .. note btw that `AnimatorController` is not the same .. a bit confusing name choice

Answer (score 0):

`GetComponent<T>` is a method, it is not a type. So, you can't declare a field with this as its type. I would be surprised if this code actually even compiles. What you want is simply

```
[SerializeField]
private Animator animator;
```

Note that `AnimatorController` is an Editor-only class; you can't include it in your game code. Hence why you want `Animator` here.

Another thing to consider is, is the Animator component going to be on the same game object? If so, you don't need to serialize the reference - that would only be useful if it's going to be on a different game object, and you need to store that link at edit time.

If the Animator component *is* on the same object, you can do this:

```
private Animator animator;

void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

The advantage is that you won't have to make sure the reference stays up-to-date, it will be connected whenever the gameplay starts. This, by the way, is the correct use of `GetComponent<T>` - since it's a method, you can call it within another method, not where you had it in your File2.